# Does COD MW2 have offline splitscreen multiplayer?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I'm considering purchasing Call of Duty Modern Warfare 2 for Xbox 360, but I'm really confused about the multiplayer options. Most of the results on the internet are either regarding 4 player ONLINE split screen multiplayer. Any answers actually regarding my question all have untrustworthy sources contradicting each other.

Can I play 4 player split screen multiplayer on Call of Duty Modern Warfare 2 offline (e.g capture the flag, deathmatch)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Any rewards and experience earned online can also be used in the offline split-screen mode.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Warfare_2

Comment: Per my recollection, you have the *option* to enabled rewards earned online.  I think there is a checkbox for that somewhere.